# Replacing elements in array by the larger of its neighbour

Tags: java, arrays, replace, element

I'm currently stuck on this one assignment where I don't know if I got the instructions wrong, or if the code is as it should be. The instructions is: 
Replace each element except the first and last by the larger of its two neighbors.

I've completed the code, but the one problem I have is that the last element is being replaced even though it shouldn't. It'd very nice if you could take a look at my code.

```
public static void replaceWithNeighbours(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            int larger = array[i - 1];

            if (larger < array[i + 1]) {
                larger = array[i + 1];
            }

            array[i] = larger;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example input and output?

Comment: If your array contains 10 values, those have index 0 to 9. You currently iterate over indexes 1 to 9. You should do array.lenght - 2. Minus 1 because the index starts at 0 and minus 1 because you want to ignore the last index.

Comment: No he does not. It's `<`, not `<=`, iteration is from 1 to 8 here: `array.length - 1 = 9`, smaller than results in `8`. Solution seems fine to me on first glance.

Comment: If i were to put 2, 18, 29 ,30 , 2, 5 , 40, 35, 5 ,2 to input, I'd recieve: 2,18,29,30,30,30,40,40,5. The last number, which is 2, always gets left out of the output.

Comment: I just ran the function. Input: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0], output: [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,0]. This is fine. However, there is an issue: You compare with the updated values, this is why for example it is two 9 at indices 7 and 8. You need to use the old array as input and compare to the original values. See this case at index 8: You expect the comparison between 8 and 0 to result in 8. However the 8 has been replaced in the previous iteration by a 9, so 9 is the incorrect result.

Comment: @Mär: isn't that the answer (instead of a comment)?

Comment: Ran the function on your numbers. Result: [2, 29, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 2] Apart from the problem that you use the array you are updating as input this is what I'd expect. I should point out that I use a return value to return the `int [] array`

Comment: @Mär So how do i fix it so the last number (2) shows up correctly? Why does it for you but not for me?

Comment: Since I don't see the behavior with the exactly same input data I suspect your code may differ from what is posted. I have printed out the indices to be on the safe side, it is from 1-8, so you manipulate index 9 elsewhere, but not in the code you provided

Comment: @Mär Here is the complete code, if you could take a look at it It'd be greatly appreciated. https://pastebin.com/6HPh1uhM

Comment: Don't have time to look through your code. I will post a solution for the function and some info what to do, so you can solve your problem

Comment: Posted a solution and some hints to find out where index 9 is accessed.

Comment: I tested your program using the numbers you gave:  2, 18, 29 ,30 , 2, 5 , 40, 35, 5 ,2. The reason you don't get 2 at the end is because you shift the numbers in the array (so the last element is now actually 5) before you do the neighbours method.

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution, the array management can be done better, however this works.

```
public static void replaceWithNeighbours(int[] array, int[] out) throws Exception
{
    // checkif lengths match
    if (array.length != out.length)
    {
        throw new Exception("Lengths don't match");
    }

    // replace values in output array
    out[0] = array[0];
    out[out.length - 1] = array[array.length - 1];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++) {

        int larger = array[i - 1];

        if (larger < array[i + 1]) {
            larger = array[i + 1];
        }

        out[i] = larger;
    }
}
```

Your main problem is that you iterate over the array and update it, however do not consider previous iterations. This means you can look at a neighbor who already holds an updated value and use this value, because the old is overwritten.

Since you also have a problem with the last element being updated:

Go through your code using the debugger or simple print statements and find out where exactly your index 9 is actually accessed. It is not in `replaceWithNeighbours`, so must be somewhere else. You can solve this by yourself however, just look what indices are used and when you see a 9, look for what is entered and where.

Comment: Instead of the exception you can just use a print statement for your purposes.

Comment: Okay, I understand a bit more now. If I were to print this, it throws an unresolved compilation problem, which is understandable since I've still got 
                                                                   
                   replaceWithNeighbours(out);                                                              
               System.out.printf("Ersätter element med grannar: %s\n", 
        Arrays.toString(array));                                                                                     But how do I print out the function now, since there's two arrays?

Comment: Create an additional empty array with the same amount of elements. Pass both to your function. Print using two print-statements for example, or just print the new array, which is `out`.

Comment: E.g.: `System.out.printf("Ersätter element med grannar: %s\n", Arrays.toString(array1), "\n", Arrays.toString(array2));`

Comment: Also, since you may want to create your output in the function rather than passing two arrays to the function, where one is for your output, you may want to consider using `ArrayList`.

Comment: The weird this is, when I change to replaceWithNeighbours(out) and then try printing out, it says out cannot be resolved to a variable, even though I created it inside of the method (int[] out) like you did. Why is it not working?

Comment: I didn't create any array in the method, I added a parameter to `replaceWithNeighbours`. If you want to use the function posted in the answer as is, then you need to pass two arrays: `in`, `out` for example. So the function call will look like this: `replaceWithNeighbours(in, out);`. They must have the same length, `in` holds your input-data, `out` can be empty and will store the output, this is what you want to print. Make sure that `out` has allocated size for 10 elements, or you will get errors.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I fixed it now, but I still can't get the last digit to stay the same...

Comment: As already explained: Use print statements throughout your entire code and print always a pair - the index and the value, whereever your arrays are accessed. When you see a `9` - look what value is being written. This way you identify the access at fault. This is what debugging often looks like.

Comment: Even better, use a debugger instead of print.

Comment: When you print your `i` in the loop - what values do you get?

Comment: We haven't gotten into it so I have no idea how to. Can't you just tell me what is causing this issue? i've been stuck on this task for multiple hours now.,.

Comment: No, I am not going to solve your problem for you. All tools and explanations are provided, personally I have spent on this question a lot more time than I intended to.

Comment: @Griezy you don't actually have an issue. Your replaceWithNeighbours method works fine. Your problem is that you are not sending the array you think you are sending it. That's because you shift the array elements before you call the method.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a simple way:

```
public int[] replaceWithNeighbours(int[] arr) {
    int[] ret = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (i == 0 || i == arr.length - 1) {
            ret[i] = arr[i];
        } else {
            ret[i] = Math.max(arr[i-1], arr[i+1]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

A short explanation: first we create a new array `ret` which will hold desired result and set it to the same length as original array. Then we loop over contents of original array. If we're dealing with first or last element we just copy them to `ret`. If we're dealing with other elements, we use Java's `Math.max` method to determine maximum value of 2 neighbours and set i-th element in `ret` to that value.